# Migrate from Gradle to Maven

Tags: java, maven, gradle

Are there any tools or recipes to migrate a Java project from Gradle to Maven?

Ideally, this would work like

```
$ ./gradlew gradle2maven
$ mvn install
```

EDIT: To those who closed this question: Did you read *and* understand my question? It is not about generating a POM so that my project can be used as a dependency of a Maven project. It is about *building* my project with Maven.

Comment: The linked question answers exactly that question AFAICS. If not, a better explanation is in order.